# Set a UIViewController behind another one as a background image

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I do not know if is it even posible. I was wondering if I could place a second UIImageView behind another one sort of like a "background reference image". I am doing it programmatically say I have `MainViewController` as the main UIViewController then I have the `secondViewController` where the logic of the app takes place and a `thirdViewController` that will hold a `UIImage.image` as the background for the `secondViewController`

This is my `MainViewController`

```
import UIKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController {
    
  
    
    let canvasView =  secondViewController()
    let canvasBackground  = thirdViewController()
 
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        
        canvas()
    }
    
    func canvas() {
        addChild(canvasView)
        
        
        view.addSubview(canvasView.view)
        
        canvasView.didMove(toParent: self)
        
        
    }
}
```

Here is my `secondViewController`

```
class secondViewController: UIViewController {

 private let mainImageView: UIImageView = {
       var imageView = UIImageView()
       imageView.backgroundColor = .clear    
       return imageView
    }()
// some more code and logic implementation

   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

And the `thirdViewController`

```
class thirdViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private let viewLayer: UIImageView = {
       let layerView = UIImageView()
        layerView.backgroundColor = .systemGreen
        return layerView
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(viewLayer)
        viewLayer.frame = view.bounds

    }
}
```

I tried to set the `mainImageView.backgroundColor` inside `secondViewController`  to .clear to make it transparent and have the `thirdViewController` image visible in the background.

Any ideas or suggestion on how to make this work will be much appreciate it.

Comment: You could do it, but why?  Why not just add the background view to the second view controller?

Comment: @Paulw11 Great. Well I have some content in my secondViewController that I want to save but I do not want its .image to be affected for that I want to pass it to the thirdViewController.image to serve as the background for my secondViewController

Comment: Well, even if you used another view controller, you would be having a container view in your secondViewController to hold its content - It would still be part of the view hierarchy of the secondViewController.  You need to specifically hide or exclude the background view when you save your content.

Answer (score 0):

The key you are looking for may be in `modalPresentationStyle` property of the view controller on top. Setting it to `overCurrentContext` with clear background it will render whatever is beneath it. So you can present a view controller with such settings over your image view controller to get to your result.

This is what I used to verify it:

```
class OverlayViewControllers {
    
    private init() {}
    
    class ImageViewController: UIViewController {
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "addSomeImageHere"))
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            imageView.backgroundColor = .white
            view.addSubview(imageView)
            imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addConstraints([
                .init(item: imageView, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0),
                .init(item: imageView, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0),
                .init(item: imageView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0),
                .init(item: imageView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
            ])
        }
        
    }
    
    class ContentViewController: UIViewController {
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            let circle = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 100, height: 100))
            circle.layer.cornerRadius = circle.bounds.width/2
            view.addSubview(circle)
            circle.center = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.midX, y: view.bounds.midY)
            circle.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        }
        
    }
    
    static func showContentViewController(_ contentViewController: UIViewController = ContentViewController(), onTopOf backgroundViewController: UIViewController = ImageViewController(), on presentationViewController: UIViewController) {
        backgroundViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        contentViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        
        presentationViewController.present(backgroundViewController, animated: false) {
            backgroundViewController.present(contentViewController, animated: false)
        }
    }
    
    
}
```

And used as

```
OverlayViewControllers.showContentViewController(on: self)
```

Obviously you can use Storyboard for most of the integration but doing it code may look more clear what is going on.